# preventDefault() on first touch but still allow scrolling/touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few elements on my site in which there is content that only appears when you hover on the element. A perfect example would be the Instagram feed grid. I'm pulling in the last 8 images from an Instagram account using their API and displaying them in a grid with flexbox. When you `:hover` over one of the images with a mouse, a semi-transparent black overlay fades in, containing the caption of the Instagram post.

On desktop you are able to click anywhere on the image/hovered caption overlay as they are both wrapped in an `<a>` element and doing so takes you to the post on Instagram's website. This works perfectly on desktop, but on touch devices does not.

Because you can't `:hover` on touch devices, I decided to implement some javascript on the `touchstart` event that uses `e.preventDefault()` to stop the link from being clicked when you tap the Instagram image and instead adds the CSS `opacity: 1` and `visibility: visible` to the overlay element (which is what happens when you `:hover` on the element). Because the overlay element is then "on top" of the image when it's made `visible`, the link is clickable because the `touchstart` event is only listened for on the image.

This all works great and means that I can tap **once** on the image which fades in the overlay and doesn't take me to the image on Instagram, and I can then click for the `second` time on the overlay, taking me to the image on Instagram.

**The problem**

Because I am using `e.preventDefault()` in the `touchstart` event, if you touch the image and then start dragging your finger to scroll, the page doesn't scroll at all which results in a bad user experience.

**So...**

How can I only `preventDefault()` on a single `touch` event, or how can I prevent the link from being clicked on the first touch of the element but not on the second whilst still allowing the user to scroll/drag the page?

**Slightly simplified version of my code**

```js
function toggleHoveredStateOn(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let hoverElem = this.querySelector('.js-touch-hover');
    
    // remove all 'visible' classes from other "hovered" items first
    document.querySelectorAll('.js-touch-trigger').forEach(touchTrigger => {
        
        let hoverElem = touchTrigger.querySelector('.js-touch-hover');
        
        Object.assign(hoverElem.style, {
            visibility: 'hidden',
            opacity: '0',
            pointerEvents: 'none'
        });
        
    });
    
    // add visible to the touched element's hover element
    Object.assign(hoverElem.style, {
        visibility: 'visible',
        opacity: '1',
        pointerEvents: 'all'
    });
    
}

function initMobileTouchFunctionality() {
    
    let touchTriggers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.js-touch-trigger')];
    
    touchTriggers.forEach(touchTrigger => {
        touchTrigger.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleHoveredStateOn, false);
        touchTrigger.querySelector('.js-touch-hover').addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }, false);
    });
    
}

initMobileTouchFunctionality();
```

```css
.flex-grid__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 263px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;

  &:hover {

    .flex-grid--social__hover {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

.flex-grid--social__hover {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid__item js-touch-trigger">
    <a href="<?php // link to instagram. php code gets this ?>">
        <img class="" src="<?php // instagram image. php code gets this ?>"/>
        <div class="flex-grid--social__hover js-touch-hover">
            <p><?php // instagram caption. php gets this ?></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark... not sure at all this would work. But perhaps you could save the info you need to re-create the original touchstart event that you do the preventDefault() on, then dispatch a new touchstart event if you detect dragging? The event you create won't be considered a "trusted" event, so I'm not sure if that will cause a problem or not.

Comment: @kshetline hmmm I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean or how I'd even go about doing it, I'd prefer a less hacky solution but I could give this a go if nothing else works

Answer (score 0):

You can decide whether to `e.preventDefault` or not using the `e.target` to see if the user tapped the image or the overlay. 
You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: I know that but it's irrelevant for my problem. I only need to detect a touch on one element (the image) and stop the user from visiting the link straight away when clicking that, after the link visiting has been prevented on the first touch I no longer need to listen for touches on the image as it has been covered by the overlay. I will always need to `preventDefault` on the image unless there is another way to do it.